# Append row from one dataframe to next when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I want to identify the last entry in a column of repeating values before the value changes and pass the whole row for that entry to a new dataframe.

`df1[location]` repeats for multiple rows before changing to a new repeating location. I only need the last row for location x before it changes to location y and passes that row to `df2`, then repeat for location y and so forth.

I have a for loop to identify the last entry for location x but need a way to append the row associated with said entry to new dataframe

```py
prev_loc = None
for loc in df1['location']
    if loc == prev_loc:
        pass
    else:
        #????
    prev_loc = loc
```

`df2` would have the same column structure of `df1` with just a subset of rows corresponding to the last entry for a given location.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the following input DataFrame:

```
    c1   c2   c3
0  120  215  393
1  120  218  396
2  120  213  399
3  130  366  301
4  130  144  302
5  130  208  303
```

It contains 2 groups with the same *c1* (120 and 130).

To get the **last row** from each group, run:

```
df.groupby('c1').last().reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
    c1   c2   c3
0  120  213  399
1  130  208  303
```

Another solution, if you want also the key of the last row:

```
df.groupby('c1').tail(1)
```

This time you will get:

```
    c1   c2   c3
2  120  213  399
5  130  208  303
```